# Xcode 8 logs out my developer account saying "session has expired"

Tags: xcode8, apple-id

When I am using my developer account, I am getting this message in Xcode  8.

> Your session has expired. Please log in.

With another Apple ID it works. Also when logging in to developer.apple.com everything is okay; I log in without a problem. How can I fix this?

Comment: I confirm that 2 factors authentication solve this issue. Don't know if Apple decide to force developers to use 2 factors authentication or if a temporary issue.

Comment: People, **don't** change your password attempting to fix this. If you do, you'll be locked out of adding 2FA for 3 days, which seems to be needed here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just added two factor authentication to my Apple ID and Xcode was fine again. Don't know how it's related but it worked for me. Do the same.

Comment: I guess that changing password is not a good idea. It looks like magic.

Comment: Don't know the exact reason but seems like adding two factor auth kinda resets the cookies or clears open sessions, maybe.

Comment: hehe, "TWO-STEP VERIFICATION
Come back after 07:45 PM (GMT) on December 18, 2016 to set up two-step verification."

Comment: I had to go to System Preferences > iCloud. Sign in and then enable two factor authentication, and thats it.. everything seems to be working...

Comment: is this a High quality post ?
stackoverflow review stuff sure has its flaws

Comment: @maazza what do you mean?

Comment: @SatnamSync http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341298/603977 is probably what maazza is referring to.

Answer (score 3):

As @Satam Sync suggested activation of two factor authentication seems to work.
If you already use it you can try deactivate end reactivate it.

For your interest this is the support answer from Apple I received:

> Hello Oliver,
>
> My name is Steffen from Apple Developer Program Support and I am happy
>   to assist you today.
>
> I understand that you receive an error message stating your session
>   has expired when trying to login to Xcode. We are aware of the issue
>   and we are working with priority yo resolve the issue as soon as
>   possible.
>
> We kindly ask you to try to login again at a later time. We apologize
>   for any inconvenience this may cause in the meantime.  We hope and
>   thank you for your understanding. As mentioned please try to doing
>   again after a few hours.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Steffen Apple Inc.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has fixed the issue (at least for the moment). No need for the suggested two factor authentication workaround.